# Issue Using PHP Script on Bluehost in Android Application

Tags: java, php, android, bluehost

I am having a problem running my PHP script to store login/registration details into MySQL Database on a Bluehost site.

S placed my PHP files in `public_html/mobileapp/registration/` on the server. I have three files: `config.php`, `db_connect.php` and `db_functions.php`. (I used these same functions in local test using localhost and they worked fine). Here are my database connection details:

```
define('DB_USER', "user"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', "password"); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "test"); 
define('DB_HOST', "server-name.com");

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

I can access these files from `server-name.com/mobileapp/registration/` and I don't get an error. However, in my Android App/Java code I keep getting a 404 Page Not Found error, and see this in the error log for Bluehost server:

```
[Sun Jan 19 20:09:12 2014] [error] [client 184.65.36.11] Attempt to serve directory: /public_html/mobileapp/registration/
```

So my question is, what page is it not finding? The PHP Script?

Sorry if its an easy question but I can't figure it out. From some searching online the Attempt to server directory error has to do with the DirectoryIndex?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Instead, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my script to use mysqli_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am somewhat confused by this question. There are only a handful of things that are likely to occur when accessing a directory without a filename specified as an end result.

1. There is an existing permalink structure that will handle this.
2. You are served with a listing of the files in the directory (less options -indexes).
3. You will be served with the default page found through hierarchical traversing the `DirectoryIndex` directive.
4. You will be served a 403 error due to the a DirectoryIndex not found, options -indexes being present and there is no permalink structure to handle this request.

In your case, the scenario that you've described is **only** possible if there is a permalink structure that is specifically for non-mobile platforms.

Otherwise, inside of `public_html/mobileapp/registration/` make an `.htaccess` file and then give it a directory index.

```
DirectoryIndex config.php index.php index.html
```

By default, this will serve `config.php` if it exists. if not, then it will serve `index.php` so on and so forth.

Comment: You are the man! Turns out I forgot the index.php :(. I added the index.php but now it does not find my db_functions.php. Its looking for it in an include folder. So I I added another folder inside public_html/mobileapp/registration and called it include and added by config, db_connect and db_functions files to it but I still get this error: "PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'include/DB_Functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in /home4/geronim9/public_html/mobileapp/registration/index.php on line 18'

Comment: When I try to navigate to the Registration folder using the browser (Chrome) it gives me access denied, but the permissions for the folder are 755

Comment: Figured it out. Turns out in my require_once() I had the file name as DB_Functions while the actual file was lower case:  db_functions. Now it all works. Thanks again for helping out!

Comment: @TudorHofnar Glad to hear you got that all sorted.

Answer (score -1):

[Escalate Hosting](http://www.escalatehosting.com/special/645199) actually in depth tutorials for these exact kinds of issues. 
Maybe not with bluehost, no. But they do have an extensive database of tutorials for different kinds of scripting for different types of OSs.